# httpwebrequest slow down in a while loop

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

In c#, I've created a task to run. It runs ok but after 55+ to 300+ repeats, each loop takes longer and longer to complete. What's wrong?

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            string url = "http://xxxx/getall";
            string token = "dddd";
            string sendData = "{somejson}"
            while (true)
            {
                //this gets slower and slower after 50-300+ repeats
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);//create
                req.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.Accept = "application/json";
                req.Method = "POST";
                var stream_req = req.GetRequestStream();//create
                byte[] reqdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendData);
                stream_req.Write(reqdata, 0, reqdata.Length);
                stream_req.Close();
                var response = req.GetResponse();//create
                //get response
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());//create
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()+":"+json.Substring(0, 20)); 
                i++;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is the server going to be slower, or the client code ?

Comment: Is this some kind of load testing ?

Comment: What's the point of using `Task.Run` if you use the *blocking* version of the methods?

Comment: Another tip: Use HttpClient for requests with async methods and create the HttpClient only once and reuse the instance for multiple requests - this is a lot faster and does not use so many sockets.

Comment: @rboe Thanks for your reply. server doesn't even warmed up by this... <5% cpu load. It's totally stuck at the client side. I'll try HttpClient and reuse it but just want to understand HttpWebRequest too, how to fix httpwebrequest

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Respectfully, it's my understanding that task runs in a threadpool so it has already using a different thread than the main ui thread, which means, i must use blocking version of the request. not begingetresponse or beginggetrequest (async version). When you do not use task, that's where you use begingetresponse and you make a new callback handler to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not caused by client code but server side. It turn out that the server has a automatic threshold limit that will react when necessary.

I've tested,this code piece has no problem at all against some other server url.